# how to join multiple tables in linq using flag field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, join, linq-to-entities

This is join query code in this contains 3 tables one tblinvoice, tblClient, TblCustomer. in Tblinvoice is contains one flag field in that contains "Customer" then i need to join invoice and customer table or it contains Client then i need to join invoice and client table how i can do this pls some one help me friends. . .

```
public class InvoiceJoin
{
    private TblInvoice invoice;
    private TblClient client;
    private TblCustomer Customer;
    public InvoiceJoin(TblInvoice invoice, TblClient client)
    {
        this.invoice = invoice;
        this.client = client;
        //this.Customer = Customer;
        //...
    }
    public string RakeNumber { get { return invoice.RakeNumber; } set { invoice.RakeNumber = value; } }
    public string partyCode { get { return invoice.ReceiverCode; } set { invoice.ReceiverCode = value; } }
    public string invoiceNum { get { return invoice.InvoiceNumber; } set { invoice.InvoiceNumber = value; } }
    //... ather invoice properties you want to see in grid

    public string ClientCode { get { return client.ClientCode; } set { client.ClientCode = value; } }
    public string ClientName { get { return client.ClientAddress1; } set { client.ClientAddress1 = value; } }        
    // ...ather clientproperties you want to see in grid
}
```

and my data loading method

```
 List<InvoiceJoin> datalist = (from invoice in _godownEntity.TblInvoices
                                   join client in _godownEntity.TblClients
                                   on invoice.ReceiverCode equals client.ClientCode
                                   select new { Invoice = invoice, Client = client }).ToList() // until this road will be done on SQL servrer
                      .Select(n => new InvoiceJoin(n.Invoice, n.Client)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking for how to join these tables in Linq, this is the syntax (If else, tell in comment) :
Place the Primary and Foreign key instead on X & Y

```
var Query = (from invoice in _godownEntity.TblInvoices
             join client in _godownEntity.TblClients on invoice.ReceiverCode equals client.ClientCode
             join customer in _godownEntity.TblCustomers on invoice.**X** equals customer.**Y**
             select *WHAT U WANT*
```

Comment: no friend i have 3 tables one is invoice , then client and last one godown. In invoice table have one field name is InvoiceType in that field value is 1 i need to join with invoice and client table otherwise i need to join with invoice and godown table can you understand friend